# JTable not updating when model updates

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

Ok, I have read up on this, but I'm still very confused. I have a JTable with a custom Table Model that stores data in an ArrayList. It displays just fine. However, when I want to add a row, I add an object to the ArrayList, then call fireTableRowsInserted(...). However, the table does not refresh.

```
public Main() {
        initComponents();
        current_map = new Map();
        current_map.authors.add(new Author("New Author"));
        author_model = new AuthorModel(current_map.authors);
        jTable1.setModel(new AuthorModel(current_map.authors)); <---This is the mistake
    }   
...     



    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        author_model.authors.add(new Author("New Author"));
        author_model.fireTableRowsInserted(author_model.authors.size(), author_model.authors.size());
    }
```

The above code is from my main JFrame. Not sure where to go from here.

I'm lost right now.

Comment: Don't invoke the fireXXX methods of the TableModel directly. These method should only be invoked by the TableModel class itself.

Comment: Ah, so the update will occur automatically then? I'll try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is initialized with:

```
jTable1.setModel(new AuthorModel(current_map.authors));
```

But when the button is clicked, you modify the variable author_model:

```
author_model.authors.add(new Author("New Author"));
```

The initialization of the table should be

```
jTable1.setModel(author_model);
```

You should also respect the Java naming conventions, and choose better names for your variables.

Comment: Oh, duh, how did I miss that one. I know the names are not good, they are temporary.

Comment: author_model should be authorModel. Same for current_map. Variables are camelCased in Java.

Comment: In addition, with regards to "temporary names": you should *always* put thought into even the simplest of projects. Underestimation has time and time again proven to be a problem (e.g., creating the internet? who would EVER need more than 4 billion IP addresses?). If you ever end up expanding this project - or even just copying some of the code to use in another project - issues like these will befuddle you and others. And if this somehow gets into a public API... \*shudder\*

Comment: I would echo this, also that effort put into naming things is always worth it.  Get into the habit of telling your readers the truth about everything you name: variables, classes, methods, packages.  The chances that those names live on after a "temporary" period is too great.  Besides, the greatest need for them is at the beginning, while you're trying to debug things like this...